# Find Controls which are not identified by CodedUI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

How to Find Controls which are not identified by CodedUI.
I have a Table in which after right clicking a Field Chooser is open, and I am unable to find controls of Fields inside this popup, only thing I can identified is scroll bar and close button, I have also tried GetChildren but no use
Its a Desktop application and I am using CodedUI to automate.

Answer (score 0):

Is this scenario what you're talking about?

[Context Menu reading in CodedUI](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c5a8172-2d82-420c-8289-f0183d6ecd16/context-menu-reading-in-codedui?forum=vsautotest)